# "According to information obtained by the website 'Syrian correspondent' that a meeting…"

Tags: syntax

> According to information obtained by the website "Syrian correspondent" **that** a meeting chaired by the head of air force intelligence, Major General "Jameel al-Hassan" on Friday, July 27 **and** included 33 officers of the intelligence services to explain the mechanism to deal with the next phase after what he called "victories" achieved by the "Arab Syrian Army".

Source: http://nedaa-sy.com/en/news/7626

I would like to ask a native speaker if he/she finds the above clause grammatically OK. I am able to catch the meaning of the clause but its syntax seems to be a little bit odd. Especially the bolded parts are in my opinion confusing. I would rewrite it in this way:

*According to information obtained by the website "Syrian correspondent" **there** was a meeting chaired by the head of air force intelligence, Major General "Jameel al-Hassan" on Friday, July 27 **that** included 33 officers of the intelligence services to explain the mechanism to deal with the next phase after what he called "victories" achieved by the "Arab Syrian Army".*

Comment: It is ungrammatical as transcribed.

Comment: I tried to leave an answer, but as a native speaker I don't actually know the rules that the quote breaks even though I can tell it's wrong. The rewrite looks fine to me, though I think there should be a comma between "According to [source]" and the rest of a sentence.

Comment: I think the infinitive clause **to explain ....** following hard upon the *that*-clause, as it does in the rewrite, is rather awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the grammar, *that* indicates a subordinate clause that often works as an adjectival phrase.  For example:

> I don't understand the sentence **that** appeared on the website.

"That appeared on the website" modifies the noun "sentence".  In your example, we might expect the subordinate clause to modify "information".  For example

> According to the information (obtained by the website *Syrian Correspondent*) that there was a meeting chaired by X and which included Y, and was for the purposes of Z ...

However, if this is the case, there is no *main clause* to the sentence.  All the *who* and *when* and *why* is structured as a *predicate* to something else, but we're left hanging.

Because there is no main clause, it's unclear what the writer really wants to say with this sentence.  Here's my best guess, adding markers to separate the various parts:

> According to information obtained by the website "Syrian Correspondent", **on** Friday, July 27 the head of Air Force Intelligence, Major General Jameel al-Hassan, **chaired** a meeting **which** included 33 officers of the intelligence services, **and which was held** to explain the mechanism to deal with the next phase after what he called "victories" achieved by the "Arab Syrian Army".

As written, it's still a bit of an overly complicated run-on sentence, that might be best broken into parts.  But it should be grammatical and easier to understand, plus it focuses what seems to be the most important information in the sentence (the *why*) at the end where the reader is sure to catch it.

Comment: Were the officers included so that they could explain ... ? Or was the meeting held to explain?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  I thought to carry through the ambiguity that was in the original -- but you're right, it's better to be clear.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way it could be rewritten:

According to information obtained by the website "Syrian correspondent", a meeting  attended by 33 officers of the intelligence services and chaired by head of air force intelligence, Major General Jameel al-Hassan, was held on Friday July 27th to explain the mechanism for dealing with the next phase following upon what al-Hassan called  Arab Syrian Army "victories".